# Read data from the table and then send that data in a table format in an email spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am new to spring batch. I am currently working on a task where I need to send an email if the job fails or succeeds. The content of the email will be a database table columns which I have to read and then create a table format in the email body and send that table in an email. 
Is there a way I could do this in spring batch?
I tried to find such a scenario on stackoverflow but I haven't been able to find something similar.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `JobExecutionListener` and implement `afterJob()` , and register it when you configure the job. This method will be called just after finish executing a job. At there, you can access the `JobExecution` and its job status/exit status to check if the job fails or succeeds and do the action accordingly.

See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#interceptingJobExecution) for more details.

For sending email using Spring , you can look at [JavaMailSender](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#mail)